# Python typing for function that returns None if list arg only contains None

Tags: python, mypy, typing

I'm working with a function that is a bit like this (super simplified, as an example):

```py
def foo(*stuff: None | int):
    stuff_not_none = [x for x in stuff if x is not None]
    if len(stuff_not_none) is 0:
        return None
    return sum(stuff_not_none)
```

If I call the function using:

- `foo(*[1, 2, 3])`, I'd want the return type to be inferred to `int`.
- `foo(*[None, None])`, I'd want the return type to be inferred to `None`.
- `foo(*[1, None])`, the dream would be inferred to `int`, but ok if `None | int`.

I've tried with generics / overloads, but I couldn't figure out this puzzle. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution:

```
from typing import overload

@overload
def foo(*stuff: None) -> None: ...  # type: ignore[misc]

@overload
def foo(*stuff: int | None) -> int: ...

def foo(*stuff: int | None) -> int | None:
    stuff_not_none = [x for x in stuff if x is not None]
    if len(stuff_not_none) is 0:
        return None
    return sum(stuff_not_none)
    
reveal_type(foo(None, None))  # revealed type is None
reveal_type(foo(1, 2, 3))  # revealed type is int
reveal_type(foo(None, 2, None, 4))  # revealed type is int
foo('a', 'b')  # error: no matching overload
```

Mypy *hates* this kind of thing, because the overloads overlap. But you'll find that if you add a `type: ignore` comment in the right place, it's perfectly able to infer the correct types anyway. (I'm a typeshed maintainer, and we do this kind of thing at typeshed *all the time*.)

Note that the order of the overloads is very important: type checkers will always try the first overload first, and then, only if that doesn't match, will they try the second overload. This is how we get the `int` revealed type when we pass in a mixture of `int`s and `None`s: the first overload doesn't match, because of the presence of `int`s, so the type checker is forced to try the second overload.

Mypy playground demo: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=ff07808e0a314208fdfa6291dcf9f717

Comment: you glorious type wizard. You even made my dream come true. I got close but I didn't have the `# type: ignore[misc]` incantation or the `int | None` on that second overload.

Comment: Brb, putting "glorious type wizard" on my CV :D

Comment: Hit a wall with this thing. I'm working with code that's not fully typed yet. I've got a bunch of `Unknown` / `Any`. If I have `bar: Any = 1`, and I call `foo(bar, bar)`, the revealed type is `None`. How can I make it `int | None` ?

Comment: Hard to tell without a proper repro, but maybe `typing.cast`? https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=5697819ad5179b0722152adf886a94e5

Comment: Turns out, the first thing that appears in the overloads is what's going to get used by vscode. So, switching up the order made it work.